# If AM-GM fails for some list of $n_0\ge 2$ numbers, then for all $n\ge n_0$, there's a list of $n$ numbers such that AM-GM fails

Tags: means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

[the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGUqE.png)

I want to prove this by induction, but I'm stuck.

In the induction step, I assume that there's a list of $n$ numbers such that the inequality fails, and then I should find a list of $n+1$ numbers such that the inequality fails, but i'm kind of stuck. Could I get a hint on how to continue?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Suppose $(a_1\cdots a_{n_0})<1$.Then $(a_1\cdots a_{n_0})^{1/n_0}<(a_1\cdots a_{n_o})^{1/n_1} $
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n_0}+\epsilon}{n_1}
&<\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n_0}+\epsilon}{n_0}\\
&<(a_1\cdots a_{n_0})^{1/n_0}+\frac{\epsilon}{n_0}\\
&\leq (a_1\cdots a_{n_0})^{1/n_1}
\end{align*}
by choosing $\frac{\epsilon}{n_0}< (a_1\cdots a_{n_0})^{1/n_1}-(a_1\cdots a_{n_0})^{1/n_0}$.

If $(a_1\cdots a_{n_0})\geq 1$, we can muyltiply the seqeunce $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n_0}$ by some small enough constant $c$ where $0<c<1$ such that $(ca_1\cdots ca_{n_0})<1$. Then repeat the arugment from above.